# How to replace string between two words including these words with Regex Class

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to replace the content between two words, including those words using Regex.

From:

```
Bezeichnung:2020,0222104,Tkl,2KB,PO1,1,4599514Meßdatei:VorlagenspexDatum:18.12.2018GeodL*da
```

to:

```
*dL
```

String between `Bezeichnung` and `GeodL\*da` changes so the pattern is `Bezeichnung......GeodL\*da`

Could you suggest something?

Comment: Post your code so we can help fix it.

Comment: Are you changing the whole string to just `*dL`? If so, why the need for a regex?

Comment: No, this string is a part of the bigger string... So, I need to remove all repetitions Bezeichnung......GeodL*da.

Comment: So,  the content between those two words are repeated many times and this I would like to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
            string input = "Bezeichnung:2020,0222104,Tkl,2KB,PO1,1,4599514Meßdatei:VorlagenspexDatum:18.12.2018GeodL*da";
            string pattern = "Bezeichnung:(?'data'.*)GeodL\\*da";
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            string data = match.Groups["data"].Value;
```

Comment: Thx, this is what i needed!